# Get logarithmic benchmark runtime from Caliper

Tags: java, performance, benchmarking, caliper

I've recently discovered the [Caliper benchmark framework for Java](http://code.google.com/p/caliper/) which seems like a very useful tool for microbenchmarks. I'm using it to run microbenchmarks for my vector maths library ([vectorz](https://github.com/mikera/vectorz))

However the standard "SimpleBenchmark" output gives a **linear** runtime chart which is not very useful if you have very different execution times:

```
        benchmark     ns linear runtime
  Vector3Addition   1.04 =
  Matrix3Rotation   4.92 =
VectorAddMultiple   6.29 =
    MatrixInverse 955.27 ==============================
```

How do you configure Caliper to output **logarithmic** runtime in the chart?

I'm running Caliper via code rather than from the command line: [source code here](https://github.com/mikera/vectorz/blob/master/src/test/java/mikera/vectorz/performance/PerformanceTest.java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caliper dropped support for logarithmic result display quite early in development. You can still get it in the [web app](http://microbenchmarks.appspot.com/) by clicking `linear runtime` to toggle.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know! Seems like an odd thing to drop, it is quite useful....

Comment: I was the big cheerleader for logarithmic results. We found it to be a lot less useful than we'd thought. And in the web app, most of the value comes from being able to move values that are incomparable to different columns (each column gets its own independent scale). BTW, in your case, it vaguely seems like you're lumping 4 very different benchmarks into the same class just for the convenience of running them at once, so I think it's a little unnatural.